# Provide usage statistics for Suggested Questions

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, analytics

When users ask a new question, they get suggestions about existing questions that might potentially solve the question they are about to ask. We apparently track clicks on these, but apparently there is no easy way to view the data. I've asked Shog9 about it and he suggested this would be a good addition to the mod analytics, I am hereby requesting this data to be made available somehow.

Comment: oh yes, that would be some tasty data to munch on! I know I click those a lot. I sometimes type in questions just to get those results.

Comment: I'm not against showing this in principle, but I gotta ask - what do you plan to learn from this data? Unless there's something meaningful (i.e. more than just looking at the data and going "huh. neat.") that can be done with it, I'm not sure about drawing much attention to it in the analytics section. Maybe a link in the oft-forgotten /admin/links section instead.

Comment: @AnnaLear tbh I am not sure what I'll learn from it. My assumption is people ignore these links. It's really just curiosity about whether that assumption is right. And since Shog said it's a good idea, I asked it. Apart from that I guess they could be the basis for measuring the effects on improvements we try in the future. There is one other idea I have in mind how these could prove useful but that needs much more thought before I'd suggest it here. See  Blue Moon.